# Android app with Facebook Login not working for other phones except mine

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

Can't figure out why my Android app with Facebook Login (SDK 3.6) is only working with my phone only. And by that I mean it won't get past the Login Activity. When another person tries to test the app (running it in Eclipse), they click the Login with Facebook button and it asks their permission to access their Facebook info. When they click ok, it brings it back to the Login Activity as if nothing happened.

I am still in the development phase so I am trying to test the app through .

I am thinking that when I gave all the project files to the other person to test, it still has my `Session` information logged in? Two different Facebook accounts btw.

I generate the `keyhash` while running the program. The block of code is in there.

**LoginActivity code**

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

private static final int HTTP_RESPONSE_SUCCESS = 200;

private Preferences prefs;
public List<GraphUser> fbFriends;

private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    getActionBar().setTitle("");

    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    prefs = new Preferences(this);

    getKeyHash();
}

private void goToMainActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private void getKeyHash() {
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.walintukai.derpteam", 
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.i("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } 
    catch (NameNotFoundException e) { } 
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) { }
}

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (session.isOpened()) {
        Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                if (user != null) {
                    prefs.setFbUserId(user.getId());
                    prefs.setFbUserName(user.getName());
                    Log.i("FB LOGIN", user.getName());
                }
            }
        }).executeAsync();

        requestFacebookFriends(Session.getActiveSession());
        goToMainActivity();
    }
    else if (session.isClosed()) {
        Log.i("FB LOGOUT", "");
        prefs.setFbUserId("");
        prefs.setFbUserName("");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private void requestFacebookFriends(Session session) {
    Request friendsRequest = createRequest(session);
    friendsRequest.setCallback(new Request.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            fbFriends = getResults(response);

            JSONWriter writer = new JSONWriter(LoginActivity.this);
            writer.updateFriendsList(fbFriends);
            writer.logJson("friends.json");

            new PostToServerTask().execute();
        }
    });
    friendsRequest.executeAsync();
}

private Request createRequest(Session session) {
    Request request = Request.newGraphPathRequest(session, "me/friends", null);

    Set<String> fields = new HashSet<String>();
    String[] requiredFields = new String[] {"id", "name"};
    fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(requiredFields));

    Bundle parameters = request.getParameters();
    parameters.putString("fields", TextUtils.join(",", fields));
    request.setParameters(parameters);

    return request;
}

private List<GraphUser> getResults(Response response) {
    GraphMultiResult multiResult = response.getGraphObjectAs(GraphMultiResult.class);
    GraphObjectList<GraphObject> data = multiResult.getData();
    return data.castToListOf(GraphUser.class);
}

private class PostToServerTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private int responseCode;

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HttpPostRequest post = new HttpPostRequest(LoginActivity.this);
        post.createPost();
        post.addJSON("friends.json");
        responseCode = post.sendPost();
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (responseCode == HTTP_RESPONSE_SUCCESS ) { Log.i("POST TO SERVER", "SUCCESS"); }
        else { Log.e("POST TO SERVER", "ERROR"); }
        return;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

}

Comment: I remember when I had to deal with the FB API, I had to make my key open to others...  Could this be the problem that you are having?  I don't think unless you hard coded it into your source that it could save a state over an apk...

Comment: @JoePacker how did you make the key open to others? After reading the documentation on keyhashes, only the developer needs to add the keyhash on the FB dev page. I tried to distribute just the APK, but not working on other phones.

Comment: if you go under apps > settings > advanced look at the client token section, and insure that you have enabled all settings that you need to make this app available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was take the app out of `Sandbox Mode`. Problem solved!

Comment: what is "sandbox Mode"

Comment: @MaherIsmaail Taking it out of sandbox mode will allow any user to use the app. Not just the people in the Roles page. Go to your app in the Facebook developer panel > click Status & Review > Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public? YES

Comment: @TheNomad, "available to the general public" means how public can see this app or access it ? What it means exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

You missed one thing. Go to https://developers.facebook.com, select your app -> Settings -> Android block and add key hashes for other computers (check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/ for details)
[image]

To get hash run 
`keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64` for Mac OS
and `keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64` for windows

Comment: I have a method that generates a keyhash above in my code ->`getKeyHash`. Wouldn't that work the same because it is working for my account? I also added the other testers keyhash to the Facebook dev account.

Comment: I did this method as well and got the same `keyhash` as the one that is generated in the program itself. Still not working for other people that are testing the APK out.

Comment: @TheNomad try to build apk onto your computer and run it on several devices. If the issue isn't in keyhash it will work

Answer (score 0):

This is problem, your facebook app not public. You have to click Status&Review menu on https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ site. Then quesiton "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?" answer "YES" and save. that's all.